# python3: Read json file from url

Tags: python, json, url

In python3, I want to load [this_file](https://www.govtrack.us/data/congress/113/votes/2013/s11/data.json), which is a json format.

Basically, I want to do something like [pseudocode]:

```
>>> read_from_url = urllib.some_method_open(this_file)
>>> my_dict = json.load(read_from_url)
>>> print(my_dict['some_key'])
some value
```

Comment: What did you actually try? Your pseudocode seems close to something that would work...

Comment: That is the problem, would work... but so far I can't make it =/

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You were close:

```
import requests
import json
response = json.loads(requests.get("your_url").text)
```

Answer (score 8):

Just use json and requests modules:

```
import requests, json

content = requests.get("http://example.com")
json = json.loads(content.content)
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'`

Answer (score 5):

Or using the standard library:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

data = json.loads(urlopen(url).read().decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 4):

So you want to be able to reference specific values with inputting keys? If i think i know what you want to do, this should help you get started. You will need the libraries urlllib2, json, and bs4. just pip install them its easy.

```
import urllib2
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.govtrack.us/data/congress/113/votes/2013/s11/data.json")
content = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
newDictionary=json.loads(str(soup))
```

I used a commonly used url to practice with.

Comment: urllib2 is not available in python3. And preferably I want to use only built-in libraries

Comment: Ah, well urllib should probably do the same thing? try it out.

Comment: Nice. Just change `urllib2.urlopen` by `urllib.request.urlopen`. Thanks.

Comment: Not a problem! Glad it worked, requests is a nice library too (see answers below) some great functionality in that library.